# Не выводит в консоль результат

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, playground

не могу понять, почему консоль не выводит результат применения функции, что нужно исправить?

```
var mainArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]
func arrayMap (a: Int, n: Array<Int>  )  {
  n.map({ $0 * a })
  
}
arrayMap(a: 1, n: mainArray)
arrayMap(a: 10, n: mainArray)
arrayMap(a: 2, n: mainArray)
arrayMap(a: 0, n: mainArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода результат используйте `print()`, например:

```swift
func arrayMap(a: Int, n: [Int])  {
  print(n.map { $0 * a })
}
```